# What does B.R.U.T.E. stand for in Fortnite?

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

This question is pretty self-explanatory.

 The way B.R.U.T.E. is spelled out implies it's an acronym, but so far the only answers I've found as to what it means have been joke answers; Beastly Robot Unfair Terror Error, for example.

Could anybody tell me what B.R.U.T.E. actually stands for?

Answer (score 2):

It might not stand for anything at all, and just be named that way to look more robotic.

The [Season X Blog](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/news/season-x-blog), and the accompanying [Patch Notes](https://www.epicgames.com/fortnite/en-US/patch-notes/v10-00-patch-notes) for the B.R.U.T.E's introduction don't expand the acronym, and those are the most likely places for such information to appear.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Fortnite archive fandom's article on it](https://fortnite-archive.fandom.com/wiki/B.R.U.T.E#Trivia), there's speculation that:

> The B.R.U.T.E's name is inspired by several items' names in Save the World. - Fortnite Archive Fandom

As for what it actually stands for, I couldn't find anything other than memes either. I hope this information helps though.

Comment: Quick question; Which Items are the inspiration?

Comment: I am unfortunately not very sure.
I can do more research on it and edit my answer with my findings if you would like.